# touchesEnded not getting called after device changes orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiresponder

I am implementing `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` in my iOS application trying to detect when the user puts a finger on the screen and when he releases it.

The problem I am having is that as soon as `touchesBegan` gets called, if the user rotates the device while still holding his finger on the screen, when he lets go of the screen, `touchesEnded` does not get called.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting touchesCancelled instead?

In general, the system will call either `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled` after a `touchesBegan`, so code should deal with both.  Touches can be cancelled for various reasons, such as a gesture recognizer taking over, an non-interactive animation starting on the view, an incoming phone call, etc.

Comment: this feels like a comment as it currently is. I suggest you edit it to make it more answer-y, explaining to the OP when `touchesCancelled` gets called, and why `touchesEnded` isn't getting called in his situation.

Comment: Excellent point. Handling it in both is what did the trick. Thank you